# Wechat small program does not support Render, can there be a way to transfer solution?

Tags: typescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCZfg.png)I have a uniapp Vue3 project, which can use the syntax of vue (some functions do not support), cross-end translation to wechat small program for use. If the AG-Grid table component is used and the wechat mini program is not supported (Render) when compiling, is there any solution for medium conversion?

```
[HBuilder] 17:57:43.063 "render" is not exported by "node_modules/@dcloudio/uni-mp-vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js", imported by "node_modules/ag-grid-vue3/lib/VueComponentFactory.js".
[HBuilder] 17:57:43.064 at ../node_modules/ag-grid-vue3/lib/VueComponentFactory.js:1:39
[HBuilder] 17:57:43.076   1: import { createVNode, defineComponent, render } from 'vue';
[HBuilder] 17:57:43.083                                             ^
[HBuilder] 17:57:43.086   2: export class VueComponentFactory {
[HBuilder] 17:57:43.087   3:     static getComponentDefinition(component, parent) {
[HBuilder] 17:57:43.091 Build failed with errors.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jvkk.png)

Delete render directly in the reference, can compile, but the project error, hope to have what kind of transit can be used?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TmBT.png)

Comment: Please don't share images of your code. Add the code into the post as a snippet instead.